# how can I make a triangle appear on the screen using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to make a triangle appear on the screen using OpenGL but when I run the code, a black screen appears

I am currently using a guide I found on the internet (here is the link: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/).

this is the code :

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int larghezza = 1024;
int altezza = 768;

int main (){
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (!glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "non è stato possibile inizzializzare glfw\n");
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);// 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);// utilizza OpenGL 4.1
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);//NON VOGLIO VECCHIE VERSIONI DI OPENGL

    GLFWwindow* window; // crea una finestra
    window = glfwCreateWindow(larghezza, altezza, "FINESTRA 1", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        fprintf (stderr, "Non è stato possibile aprire la finestra!\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); //inizzializza GLEW
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        fprintf (stderr, "non è stato possibile inizzializzare GLEW");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    do {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
          glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                          3,                  // size
                          GL_FLOAT,           // type
                          GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                          0,                  // stride
                          (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                          );
    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: The main loop (`do { ... } while`) has to be a the end of the code and the draw call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)` has to be in the loop (after `glClear`). Delete `glDisableVertexAttribArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glDrawArrays() call should be in the main rendering event loop. Specifically within the do {} block.

Ask: Why will this code render if your draw call does not get called while it is within the do{} loop ?

When you press the Escape button, it will draw but in the hidden buffer, which is basically swapped to the screen once the draw is completed. Since you don't swap after the glDrawArrays() call, you will never see it.

I don't know what tutorial site you are using

However, I suggest a proper tutorial like from this site - learnopengl.com. Even going through the Getting Started section is enough for a good intro.

Comment: In addition to that, the tutorial asks for a 4.1 core profile context. Depending on OPs hardware that profile might not be supported … and is complete overkill for that tutorial anyway. At this level ask for a plain 3.0 profile, or 3.3 core.